# Access VBA - Comparing two variants returns unexpected result

Tags: ms-access, vba, variant

I'm comparing 2 variants to see if one is bigger than the other. Simple stuff right? But VBA is returning the completely wrong result. When I compare Variant1>Variant2, the statement will return true even when variant 1 is smaller than variant 2.

I cant help but think this has something to do with using Variants over Doubles, but it is unfortunately necessary as that value can sometimes be set to Null.

```
Dim max As Variant
Dim val1 As Variant
Dim val2 As Variant

...
max = .Fields("Max") 'These values are pulled from a recordset where the field is a double
...
val1 = .Fields("Val1")
val2 = .Fields("Val2")
...
'val1 = .001
'val2 = .001
'max = .002
If (val1 > max) Or (val2 > max) Then
        outOfSpec = outOfSpec + Description + vbCrLf
End If
```

Comment: where is val1, val2 and max defined ?
Testing in the direct window gives me the correct result:
  Debug.Print 0.001 > 0.002
  False

Comment: I Added the variable declaration and where the values are set to the code. The values come from a recordset where the field is a double

Answer (score 0):

As it so happens I had val1 and val2 set to Text in the database. This is where the problem occurred as it was comparing a string and a double.